# How to get value from ListBoxItem 's control?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I hava a ListBox and Binding Students,I want to get "ID" when I Click "Btn". But, I don't know how to do it.Please tell me how to do?

XAML:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="12">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,StringFormat=Name:\{0\}}"
                                   Foreground="Orange"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age,StringFormat=Age:\{0\}}"
                                   Foreground="Gray"/>
                        <Button Content="Get ID Of Student"
                                x:Name="Btn"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       </ListBox>
```

C#:

```
        List<Student> students = new List<Student> 
        {
            new Student{Name = "st1",Age = 20,ID = 1},
            new Student{Name = "st2",Age = 18,ID = 2},
            new Student{Name = "st3",Age = 21,ID = 3},
        };

        listBox.ItemsSource = students;

        public class Student 
        {
               public string Name { get; set; }
               public int Age { get; set; }
               public int ID { get; set; }  
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the `ID` field to the `CommandParameter` property on the button

```
<Button Content="Get ID Of Student" 
        x:Name="Btn" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" 
        ... />
```

Then your `Command` will automatically get passed the `ID` as a parameter

If you're using the `Click` event instead of the `Command` property, you can cast the `sender` as a `Button` and check it's `CommandParameter`, or you can cast it's `DataContext` as a `Student` object and get the ID from that

```
void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;

    int id = (int)b.CommandParameter;

    // or 
    Student student = (Student)b.DataContext;
    int id = student.ID;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. but in your way, if I need get many Property, how to do it ? ex: public class Student { Name , Age , ID , Grade , Sex, Brith, City , And So On } . I want get them. I think "Tag" can't enough

Comment: @BillyMadisonnn See the last two lines of code in my answer. You cast the `DataContext` to your `Student` object, and then have access to all the student properties. As an alternative, you can bind the `CommandParameter` to the entire object (`CommandParameter="{Binding }"`, and cast the `CommandParameter` as a `Student` object instead of an `int`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Student selectedStundet = listBox.SelectedItem as Student;
```

Comment: thank you. I clike "Btn" of ListBoxItem. it isn't ListBox, so I can't get listBox.SelectItem

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button Content="Get ID Of Student" x:Name="Btn" Tag={Binding ID} Click="Button_Click" />

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        string id = b.Tag;
        ...
}
```

Then you get your student using LINQ, something like this:

```
Student a = from student in Students
          student.ID=(int)id
          select student;
```

Comment: thank you so much. but in your way, if I need get many Property, how to do it ?  ex: public class Student { Name , Age , ID , Grade , Sex, Brith, City , And So On } . I want get them.   I think "Tag" can't enough

Comment: See the answer above, I added details.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to upvote the solution(s) that you like and mark the best answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Student st = (sender as Button).DataContext as Student;
            MessageBox.Show(st.ID + "\n" + st.Age + "\n" + st.Name);
        }
```